# Any way to organize android 's id "@+id/"

Tags: android

I am wondering is there a way to organize my widget's android:id .  My app has a couple of  Activies and couple of layout.  It is hard to keep track of all the names of buttons and textviews.  My IDE would spring up a list of all the R.id.xxx from previous layouts .  Is there a way to sort them like with directory or periods, ie android:id="@+id/abc.efg" or android:id="@+id/abc/efg" .  Sort of like sub structuring them or nesting them.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way I keep track is by changing the "id" prefix to something else

ex. 
A layout for ActivityOne might have layout IDs as

```
android:id="@+activity1/textview"
```

And "TestActivity" could be

```
android:id="@+test/textview"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to always use some convention on the id naming. For example use type-of-component prefixes: *btn_somethig* for all Buttons, *et_something* for all EditText and so on... When you're looking for a particular ID, just fill-in first the type of the component.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no.  I always go by a naming convention based on what I'm looking for.  Usually it's, `type_of_id_type_of_object_name`.  So a layout could be `layout_relative_layout_main_panel`.  A sub-view like a `TextView` would be `view_text_view_text1` or something.  The detail is app-specific though.